# PinchZoom.js not working on iOS devices after 13.4 update by Apple

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pinchzoom

So I have run into a problem again with this plugin- [PinchZoom.js](http://manuelstofer.github.io/pinchzoom/) which started happening after the 13.4 update by Apple for iOS devices.

The problem is that the double tap feature has suddenly stopped working completely on iOS devices now.

For a concrete test, you can refer to the plugin demo page: http://manuelstofer.github.io/pinchzoom/demo/pinchzoom.html

On iOS devices, you won't be able to double tap to zoom in the image whereas this was working fine in previous versions of iOS.

I have even dived down in the source code of the plugin but I am not sure what is causing the double tap TO NOT work in iOS devices after the update.

If anyone has any idea/workaround for this, it would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What you could do is open a issue on Github for PinchZoom.js. This way the creator of the plugin knows about the problem and maybe is going to fix it in some time. 

https://github.com/manuelstofer/pinchzoom/issues

Comment: @Dave Thank you very much for the suggestion. I have opened up a ticket there also: https://github.com/manuelstofer/pinchzoom/issues/111

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On all browsers there used to be a delay of 300-350ms on `touchstart` events. Apparently, on iOS there still is. You can test this by logging tap events and time in the `touchstart` event listener.

And for your issue, you could either solve it by modifying pinchzoom.js to use `touchend` which has no delay instead of `touchstart`, or by preventing default behaviour on the `touchstart`.

I chose the latter and added `event.preventDefault()` to the `touchstart` event listener. You can do that too, until the developer provides an official solution.

```
el.addEventListener('touchstart', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //add this

    if (target.enabled) {
        firstMove = true;
        fingers = event.touches.length;
        detectDoubleTap(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried doing what you suggested but unforrtunately it is not working. I am still not able to double tap zoom on iPhone whereas Android is working fine as before.

Comment: Can you check if this one is working for you? https://tests.offthetopic.app/pinchzoom/. This demo I've uploaded works for me on an iPhone XR with 13.5.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only thing I've changed from your demo was this preventDefault()

Comment: Okay, that is weird cause I did exactly the same thing that you mentioned and it is not working on my site.

Comment: I double checked and this indeed is the only change.

Comment: This page works on the iPhone with 13.5, but the demo you provided in the original question doesn't.

Comment: Really? It is not working on my device. Not sure what is going on here. Which browser are you checking this on. I am checking on Safari.

Comment: Safari as well. But it shouldn’t matter anyway as all browsers on iOS use WebKit.

Comment: YES, wonderful, it is working now. It was cache issue at my end. Cleared my cache and now it is working. Many thanks

Comment: This resolved the zoom issue but caused other problems in scrolling and clicking on links on the website so I had to revert it back unfortunately

Comment: Is there an alternative for this that you can share?

Comment: An alternative would be to resort to using `touchend`, but the plugin would have to be reworked.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the above implementation? Thanks

Comment: I think this would be too much of a rewrite, so I suggest following up on that with the plugin developer.